# Django queryset: filter DateTimeField if datetime.now() is greater than field - 24 hours

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I can't understand how do this.

I have an Event model with a start_datetime field. I want to select all events where datetime.now() >= start_datetime - 24 hours.
I try with filter() but I can't understand how to tell 'start_datetime - 24h'.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you rearrange

```
datetime.now() >= start_datetime - 24 hours
```

you get

```
start_datetime <= datetime.now() + 1 day
```

So your queryset should be:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Event.objects.filter(start_datetime__lte=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
```